# How to create correlation matrix but with only part of the rows?

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to have correlation matrix like this one, but with only 3 bottom rows but all the columns. How can I generate it?

[image]

```
corr = corrdata.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=np.zeros_like(corr), annot=True, cmap=sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),
            square=True, ax=ax, fmt='.2f' ,  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a slice of the correlation matrix dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,],'B':[4,5,6,7],'C':[8,9,10,11]})
sns.heatmap(df.iloc[2:3, 1:3], annot=True, cmap=sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True),square=True, )
```